# NodeJs Async library : Why is callback not fired after an error occured?

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I've been developing the backend of an NodeJS server which currently uses the libraries 'async' and 'mysql'. Note, that these three routines are executed inside the "waterfall" function of async. It should work as follows:

- Server connects to the MySQL database
- MySQL database inserts a new entry into the table 'Tag'

  - if the server tries to insert a duplicate an error should be thrown and the test should fail
- Server disconnects from the MySQL database

Unfortunatly, every test I run with mocha still passes eventhough the MySQL client of the server tries to insert a duplicate.

I've already read the documentation for the library 'async'. It said that the control flow will be redirected to the "waterfall" callback if an error occurs during the execution of the "waterfall" function. I also tried to consult the documentatin of the "mysql" library. But I couldn't find anything which could help me with my problem. Should I put the code which could throw an error inside a try-catch block or do I have to issue a special callback?

File : SqlTagsTest.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var mySqlUtils = require('../../backend/MySqlHandler/MySqlUtils.js');
var mySqlTags = require('../../backend/MySqlHandler/MySqlTags.js');

describe('Create new tag',function(){
    var connection = "";
    var queryParams = "";
    before(function(done){
        connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host:'myHost',
            user:'root',
            password:'myPassword',
            database:'myDb'
        });
        queryParams = {
            name: 'Tag',
            description: 'Description',
            parent: 'root',
            creator: 'me',
            admin: false
        };
        done();
    });
    it('should create a new tag inside the database',function(){
        mySqlTags.CreateTag(connection,queryParams);
});
```

File: MySqlTags.js

```
var sqlUtils = require('./MySqlUtils.js');
var reflectChanges = require('./MySqlReflection.js');
var async = require('async');

function CreateTag(connection,queryParams){
  async.waterfall([
    function SetupData(callback){
      callback(null,connection,queryParams);
    },
    sqlUtils.ConnectToDatabase,
    sqlUtils.InsertTagIntoDatabase,
    sqlUtils.CloseDatabaseConnection
  ],function(err,results){
      if(err)
      {
          throw err;
      }
  });
}

function DeleteTag(connection,queryParams,serverResponse){
  async.waterfall([
    function setupData(callback){
      callback(null,connection,queryParams);
    },
    sqlUtils.ConnectToDatabase,
    reflectChanges.DeleteTagEntry,
    reflectChanges.GenerateUncategorizedTag,
    reflectChanges.UpdateChildrensParent,
    sqlUtils.CloseDatabaseConnection
  ],function(error,results){
    if(error){
      serverResponse(queryParams,error,false);
    }else{
      serverResponse(queryParams.name,true);
    }
  });
}

function EditTag(queryParams,serverResponse){
  async.waterfall([
    sqlUtils.ConnectToDatabase,
    sqlUtils.CloseDatabaseConnection
  ],function(error,results){
    if(error){
      serverResponse(queryParams.name,false);
    }else{
      console.log("No errors!");
      serverResponse(queryParams.name,true);
    }
  });
}

module.exports = {
  CreateTag: CreateTag,
  DeleteTag: DeleteTag,
  EditTag: EditTag
}
```

File : MySqlUtils.js

```
var mySql = require('mysql');
var reflectChanges = require('./MySqlReflection.js');
var async = require('async');

/**
 * connects to a MySql database 
 * @param {connection which will be established} connection 
 * @param {paremeters which are executed} queryParams 
 * @param {callback which is required by the async library} callback 
 */
function ConnectToDatabase(connection,queryParams,callback){
  connection.connect(function(error){
    if(error){
      console.log(error);
      throw error;
    }else{
       callback(null,connection,queryParams);
     }
  });
}

/**
 * closes an existing connection to the MySql database
 * @param { connection which is passed from the previous function } connection 
 * @param { callback when database connection was successfully closed } callback 
 */
function CloseDatabaseConnection(connection,queryParams,callback)
{
  connection.end(function(error)
  {
    if(error){
        throw error;
    }else{
      callback(null,connection,queryParams);
    }
  });
}

/**
 * get all files which will be affected by the particular query
 * @param {*} connection 
 * @param {*} queryParams 
 * @param {*} callback 
 */
function GetAffectedFiles(connection,queryParams,callback)
{
    const query = "SELECT Name,Tags FROM Tag";
    const params = [];
    var affectedRows = [];

    connection.query(query,params,function(error,results,fields){
        if(error){
            return connection.rollback(function(){
                throw error;
            });
        }else{
            for(var currRow = 0; currRow < results.length; currRow++)
            {
                if(results[currRow].Name === queryParams.name){
                    affectedRows.push(results[currRow].Name);
                }
            }
        }
        queryParams.affectedRows = affectedRows;
        callback(connection,queryParams,callback);
    });
}

/**
 * inserts a new tag into the database
 * @param { connection which will be passed from the previous function } connection 
 * @param { field values of the original row } queryParams 
 * @param { callback called when query was executed successfully } callback 
 */
function InsertTagIntoDatabase(connection,queryParams,callback){
  const query = "INSERT INTO Tag(Id,Name,Description,Parent,Creator,Admin) VALUES((SELECT UUID()),?,?,?,?,?)";
  const params = [queryParams.name,queryParams.description,queryParams.parent,queryParams.creator,queryParams.admin];
  connection.query(query,params,function(error,results,fields){
    if(error){
      throw error;
      throw error;
    }else{
      callback(null,connection,queryParams);
    }
  });
}

/**
 * process chain which allows will be triggered upon tag deletion
 * @param { connection which was established between } connection 
 * @param { queryParameters which will be passed to subroutines } queryParams 
 * @param { callback which will be called upon termination } callback 
 */
function ReflectTagRemoval(connection,queryParams,callback){
  async.waterfall([
    function SetupPrequisites(callback){
      callback(null,connection,queryParams);
    },
    reflect.DeleteTagEntry,
    reflect.UpdateChildrenTag,
    reflect.UpdateFileTags,
    function PassFurther()
    {
      callback(null,connection,queryParams);
    }
  ]);
}

function ReflectTagUpdate(connection,queryParams,callback){
  async.waterfall([
    function SetupPrequisites(callback){
      callback(null,connection,queryParams);
    },
    ConnectToDatabase,
    reflectChanges.EditTagEntry,
    reflectChanges.EditTagChildrenAfterChanges,
    reflectChanges.UpdateFileTagsAfterEdit,
    function PassFurther(callback){
      callback(null,connection,queryParams);
    }
  ]);
}

function ValidateLoginCredentials(connection,loginCredentials,callback)
{
  const query = "SELECT Name,Password FROM User WHERE Name = ? AND Password = ?";
  const params = [loginCredentials.username,loginCredentials.password];

  connection.query(query,params,function(error,results,fields){
    if(error)
    {
      throw error;
    }
    callback(null,connection);
  });
}

module.exports = 
{
  ConnectToDatabase: ConnectToDatabase,
  InsertTagIntoDatabase: InsertTagIntoDatabase,
  ReflectTagRemoval: ReflectTagRemoval,
  ReflectTagUpdate: ReflectTagUpdate,
  ValidateLoginCredentials: ValidateLoginCredentials,
  CloseDatabaseConnection : CloseDatabaseConnection
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question but : are your sure your `Tag` table description include a `UNIQUE` key  other than `Id` ?

Comment: Yes. The table includes the columns "Id" which is an UUID and "Name" which is an unique value of the typye "TEXT".

Comment: well, I've tried on my dev server : mysql gives an error when you insert duplicate as expected and your code seems right to me. Just a thing : when you get an error, you throw it => you should use callback(error) instead so that you could be able to manage end of connection. Can't do more, sorry. Regards

Comment: Thank you for your advice :) While I couldn't find any workaround so far, this solution gives me the possibility to send a response to the client.